# How can I track clicks within a script on my site?

Tags: javascript

I have a script from easylocator.net on my site that displays various locations our end-users can choose from. The issue is, Google Analytics doesn't track clicks on the map so I'm unable to see how many locations are being clicked, etc.

I have some access on the backend of easylocator.net, but no where to insert any sort of code, etc. It all needs to be done on my site.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an event listener on a specific element or on the window as a whole. and then from the target you can see which element was clicked.

for example

```
window.addEventListener('click', (e) => console.log('clicked on element', e.target))
```

Comment: Silly question, but would the clicks be logged in GA then?

Comment: @ihaveaquestion When you add an event listener this does not affect the previous listeners ... if GA events were working they will still continue to work

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src=http://fastonlineusers.com/online.php?d=www.mohager.co.sr></script>
<br>
<font face="Tahoma"><a target="_blank" href="http://mytempsite.com"><span style="font-size: 8pt; text-decoration: none">JavaScript Free Code</span></a></font>
```

I think this will work. Try on internet explorer or safari browser.